# How do I remove validation duplication from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, duplicates

Short of extracting shipping and billing addresses into an Address model, how can I remove this validation duplication?

I only want to validate the billing address if it's not the same as the shipping address. How would I go about extracting it into a module? An example would be really helpful as I never know what to include in modules, or `self` refers to.

```
  validates :shipping_name, :shipping_address1, :shipping_street_number, :shipping_city, presence: true
  validates :shipping_state, inclusion: { in: Address.states.values }
  validates :shipping_post_code, length: { is: 5 }, numericality: { only_integer: true }

  validates :billing_name, :billing_address1, :billing_street_number, :billing_city, presence: true, unless: -> { self.bill_to_shipping_address? }
  validates :billing_state, inclusion: { in: Address.states.values }, unless: -> { self.bill_to_shipping_address? }
  validates :billing_post_code, length: { is: 5 }, numericality: { only_integer: true }, unless: -> { self.bill_to_shipping_address? }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a method and then pass in the bits that are different between the two types of addresses. In this case, the difference is the prefix word for the fields and the ability to pass in extra options.

```
module AddressValidator
  def validates_address(type, options = {})
    validates :"#{type}_name", :"#{type}_address1", :"#{type}_street_number", :"#{type}_city", {presence: true}.merge(options)
    validates :"#{type}_state", {inclusion: { in: Address.states.values }}.merge(options)
    validates :"#{type}_post_code", {length: { is: 5 }, numericality: { only_integer: true }}.merge(options)
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend AddressValidator
  validates_address(:shipping)
  validates_address(:billing, unless: -> { self.bill_to_shipping_address? })
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to ask myself now if it's worth it.